# Targeting a specific file size in vp8+vorbis encoding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a couple videos that I want to encode to vp8 for video and Vorbis for audio. This is the FFmpeg command I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -s 640x360 -filter:v fps=20 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 200k -map 0:a:0 -b:a 48k -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

I want to have control over output file size and limit it to 3MB without clipping the video, but instead, lose quality. so I cant use `-fs 3MB`.

How can I determine the file size based on video and audio bitrates and duration?

How can I limit the file size without clipping?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for 10 second input with an output just under 3 MB output:

```
3 MB * 8000 / 10 seconds - 48kb audio bitrate - 1% muxing overhead = -b:v 2328k
```

Encode with two passes when targeting specific output file size:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -filter:v "scale=640:360,fps=20" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2328k -pass 1 output.webm
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -filter:v "scale=640:360,fps=20" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2328k -map 0:a:0 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 48k -pass 2 output.webm
```

See:

- [Get duration with `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604/)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8)